multi Select dropdown auto disappear
I have multiselect Kendo UI dropdown in a grid.
Values are getting filled properly as I can see on the form because once I click the dropdown, I can see the dropdown coming down and options showing.
But the problem is that as soon as the dropdown comes down, it gets rolled up automatically.
I am using below code.
<span title="" style="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on"
  role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns=""
  aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false"
>
  <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
      <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <input name="Equipment" required="" data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Id"
    data-bind="value:Equipment" validationmessage="Required!" data-role="dropdownlist"
    style="display: none;" class="k-invalid" aria-invalid="true"
  >
</span>

I have tried unselectable="off" but not working.
What I want is for the dropdown stay until I am done selecting any option and or click somewhere outside the dropdown.
